# Laravel Dompdf Show Blank When Display Specific Data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

When I use this query:

```
$admin = \App\Admin::all();
```

It works.

But when I use this query:

```
$admin = \App\Admin::where('status', "ACTIVE");
```

Its shows blank! Even though when I use this query to show data at blade file, it's works!

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this If you want multiple result

```
$admin = \App\Admin::where('status', "ACTIVE")->get();
```

Or if you want a single result then use this

```
$admin = \App\Admin::where('status', "ACTIVE")->first();
```